# What is an easy learn language in which unit tests make sense?

Tags: unit-testing

I am teaching a unit testing course to people who have a variety of backgrounds. I want to teach them a very easy programming language and then write unit tests in it.

What's a simple language I can teach in a couple of hours and then write unit tests in it?

Comment: This may get closed as opinion-based.  You may flag this as wiki to avoid that.

Comment: I would suggest to try groovy+spock with IntelliJ(IDE).  http://www.slideshare.net/edvorkin/unit-testing-with-spock-framework

Answer (score 1):

Definitively use an interpreted language as it is a lot easier to teach and for most of them there are plenty of libraries and tutorials on how to do unit testing. I would recommend C# as it has fantastic unit testing frameworks like NUnit that integrates very well with Visual Studio and are fully configurable. There are also many mocking frameworks like [RhinoMocks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RhinoMocks/) that are very useful to create stubs or mocks in your tests.

Comment: C# is not an interpreted language. Do you have an interpreted language that you would recommend?

Comment: C# even though it is compiled to a byte code representation like Java, it is still converted into CPU instructions at run-time (i.e. interpreted by the CLR). That byte code can be converted back to C# source code fairly easy. You can't do that with a truly compiled executable. If you want to go really simple perhaps look into python:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html